# Lucene Query String Elasticsearch "less than or equal to"[URI Search]

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

On so many websites they teach how to query data from Elasticsearch using range query. I would like to query data that is less than or equal to a certain number from Elasticsearch using Lucene Style Query String like this.

```
fieldname:[* TO 100]
```

or

```
fieldname:["*" TO "100"]
```

I have tried in other formats but none of those worked. Can someone help me?

Comment: if you are not satisfied with answers ask again.. Don't abandon the questions. Accept answers and help others..

Comment: Just tried @John Petrone 's answer and it worked. fieldname:<10

Answer (score 70):

You will want to use Query String Syntax (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) ranges combined with the URI Search (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html)

> Ranges
>
> Ranges can be specified for date, numeric or string fields. Inclusive
>   ranges are specified with square brackets [min TO max] and exclusive
>   ranges with curly brackets {min TO max}.
>
> ```
>     All days in 2012:
>
>     date:[2012/01/01 TO 2012/12/31]
>
>     Numbers 1..5
>
>     count:[1 TO 5]
>
>     Tags between alpha and omega, excluding alpha and omega:
>
>     tag:{alpha TO omega}
>
>     Numbers from 10 upwards
>
>     count:[10 TO *]
>
>     Dates before 2012
>
>     date:{* TO 2012/01/01}
>
> Curly and square brackets can be combined:
>
>     Numbers from 1 up to but not including 5
>
>     count:[1..5}
>
> Ranges with one side unbounded can use the following syntax:
>
> age:>10
> age:>=10
> age:<10
> age:<=10
>
> Note
>
> To combine an upper and lower bound with the simplified syntax, you would need to join two clauses with an AND operator:
>
> age:(>=10 AND < 20)
> age:(+>=10 +<20)
>
> The parsing of ranges in query strings can be complex and error prone. It is much more reliable to use an explicit range filter.
> ```
>
> URI Search
>
> Search URI Search Request Body Search Search Shards API Search
>   Template Facets Aggregations Suggesters Context Suggester Multi Search
>   API Count API Validate API Explain API Percolator More Like This API
>   Benchmark
>
> A search request can be executed purely using a URI by providing
>   request parameters. Not all search options are exposed when executing
>   a search using this mode, but it can be handy for quick "curl tests".
>   Here is an example:

```
$ curl -XGET
'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?q=user:kimchy'
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you wanna query the documents with less than equal to 100.

```
 curl -XPOST "http://hostname:9200/index/try/_search" -d'
{
 "query": {
    "range": {
      "FieldName": {
         "lte" : 100
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**PHP API client**

```
array(
'query' => array(
    'range' => array(
        'FieldName' => array(
            array("lte" => 100)
        )
    )
  )
);
```

for more queries.. [refer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#query-dsl-range-query)

**The query format thet you asked for..!**

```
curl -XPOST "http://hostname:9200/index/type/_search?q=FieldName:[* to 100]"
```

HOpe it helps..!

Comment: I think this is not a Lucene query string. I use a Elasticsearch PHP Client API and I don't want to use a JSON or an array format as parameter to query data but would like to use a Lucene query string instead.

Comment: It's 1.0. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: You should mention your query in which format you want.Gimme some time i ll get back to you

Comment: For example: fieldname: <= "value1". This example does not work but just give you an idea. Normally it works with: fieldname:"value1"

Answer (score 0):

## Expanding on BlackPOP's answer

It is good to know that for `range date searches` you have to use quotes otherwise the year can be interpreted as a timestamp:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#numeric-date

> When no date format is specified and the range query is targeting a date field, numeric values are interpreted representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch. If you want the value to represent a year, e.g. 2020, you need to pass it as a String value (e.g. "2020") that will be parsed according to the default format or the set format.

## Example

```
curl -s -X GET "localhost:9200/backup/_search?pretty=true" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d ' {
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "lastBackupStartTime": {"gt" : "2023-08-01"}
    }
  }
}' | jq '.hits.hits[] | ._source.id'
```