# Query events greater doesn't show results

Tags: kibana

I'm trying to query events where 'total > 500', but it doesn't work correctly. [image]
Microanalysis for field total says it's type is long.
[image]

I imported from CSV, than mutated to integer

```
mutate {
  convert => [ "total", "integer" ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution

```
total:>500
```

More info at [Lucene Query String Elasticsearch "less than or equal to"[URI Search]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674259/lucene-query-string-elasticsearch-less-than-or-equal-touri-search)